# how to use concat function in this trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have this trigger below which inserts new values in the an emplog table,i want to make my trigger to insert in the description column the event that took place for example if i changed the last_name i want it to appear old.lastname was changed to new.last_name,if its the first-name or gender or dob or marital or ssn that were updated it should do the same,im a newbie how can i achieve this lets say i want to use concat function??

```
CREATE TRIGGER emplog_update AFTER UPDATE ON emp 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO emplog VALUES 
(NEW.id,NEW.lastname,NEW.firstname,NEW.gender,NEW.dob,NEW.marital,NEW.SSN,'U',NULL,USER(),('this is where the description will go'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select` instead of `values` to generate the list of columns.

You can use `concat_ws()` to concatenate the strings together, by using case statements to compare the values.  The following version assumes that the columns do not have NULL values:

```
CREATE TRIGGER emplog_update AFTER UPDATE ON emp 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO emplog  (id, lastnmae, firstname, . . .)
    select NEW.id,NEW.lastname,NEW.firstname,NEW.gender,NEW.dob,NEW.marital,NEW.SSN,'U',NULL,USER(),
           concat_ws(',',
                     (case when new.id <> old.id then 'id' end),
                     (case when new.lastname <> old.lastname then 'lastname' end),
                     (case when new.firstname <> old.firstname then 'firstname' end),
                     . . .
                    );
```

As a note, you should list the columns for the table in the `insert` staetment.  This is good practice to keep code maintainable, and particularly important for a trigger.  If someone removes or renames a column, the trigger might fail on the next update, with an inscrutable email message.

Replace the `...` with similar code for all the columns.

Comment: im kind of getting this error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1